# Is it possible to not render text using the Ghostscript command line?

Tags: image, pdf, ghostscript

I want to do some image processing in MATLAB. However, my source files are PDF's, so I'm converting them to images using the Ghostscript command line.

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -sOutputFile=test%d.png test.pdf
```

However, there is some text overlaying the images I would like to process. Is it possible to disable the rendering of fonts? Ugly workarounds are acceptable too, like forcing `gs` to use an empty font (does such a thing exist?) or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Ghostscript (and if you aren't, then upgrade) you can use:

`-dFILTERTEXT`

See Ghostscript documentation: [**Use.htm** => "Other parameters"](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Other_parameters).